# How can be reach related entities while using generic repository in .net? how can i get category name in getproduct method?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, controller, unit-of-work

When I use the GetProducts method, I want the name of the category to come directly, not the id.
Can I provide this using generic repository.if so how.Thanks in advance for helping.

My Product Entity

```
public class Product:BaseEntity
    {
       
        public  string ProductName  { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Img1 { get; set; }
        public string Img2 { get; set; }
        public string Img3 { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public int Stock { get; set; }
        //related ent
        public Category Category{ get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
               
 
    }
```

my IGenericrepository

```
namespace Core.Interfaces
{
    public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T: BaseEntity
    {
        Task<T> GetByIdAsync(int id);
        Task<IReadOnlyList<T>> ListAllAsync();
        Task<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
        Task<bool> SaveChangesAsync();
        void Add(T entity);
        void Update(T entity);
        void Delete(T entity);
        
    }
}
```

my genericrepository

```
 public async Task<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return await _context.Set<T>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(predicate);
        }
```

my  GetProduct() method is here

```
 [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<List<Product>>>  GetProducts(){
            var products=await _productsrepo.ListAllAsync();
            return Ok(products);
        }
```

Comment: EF is already a generic repository and unit-of-work. It's generally considered a bad idea to implement another generic repository abstraction over EF.

Comment: Try `string categoryNameOfFirstProduct = products.FirstOrDefault().Category.Name;` and '`string categoryName= products.Include(p => p.Category);`